# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.HttpUrlConnectionNetworkFetcher

Tags: android, fresco

I'm trying to use Fresco but it crashes as soon as I try to initialize it.  I use Android Studio and I've been following the instructions located [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html).

In my application class I initialize Fresco just like in the tutorial in the `onCreate` method like so:

```
Fresco.initialize(this);
```

This is the stacktrace of the crash:

```
09-25 18:31:05.896    7789-7789/com.myproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.HttpUrlConnectionNetworkFetcher
        at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineConfig.<init>(ImagePipelineConfig.java:126)
        at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineConfig.<init>(ImagePipelineConfig.java:61)
        at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineConfig$Builder.build(ImagePipelineConfig.java:378)
        at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory.initialize(ImagePipelineFactory.java:77)
        at com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco.initialize(Fresco.java:32)
        at com.myproject.MyProjectApplication.onCreate(MyProjectApplication.java:196)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
  }

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 22
    versionName "0.0.22"
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
 }
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    jumboMode = true
 }
}

repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
  }
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
  compile ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0+')
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  compile(name:'httpmime-4.3.5', ext:'jar')
  compile(name:'httpcore-4.3.2', ext:'jar')
  ...
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
}

configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
}
```

**update**

I'm experiencing this on an emulator running Android version 4.1.2 and an actual phone running 4.4.4.  On Lollipop devices everything works.  [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) supports Gingerbread and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have exceeded 65K method limit. If you haven't added 'multiDexEnabled true' in defaultConfig do so. Also to support MultiDex on pre lollipop devices you have to add MultiDex compat library in your dependencies. Your build.gradle file will look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.justride"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 17
    versionCode 30
    versionName "3.0.0"
    **multiDexEnabled true**
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }


    **splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
            universalApk false
        }
    }**

}
}

repositories{
    maven {
        url "http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.13'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    **compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0+'**
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.+'
    **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'**
}
```

Also, in your project Application class override attachBaseContext() method like this:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Please tell if this is helpful. Split is used as Fresco is a native library so there is a different set of binaries for each CPU architecture and a separate .apk is built for each CPU containing only the specific set of libraries for that CPU architecture.

Update

Multidex support is by default included in ART (lollipop+). Prior to lollipop, multidex support is provided through support library. Hence, we need to include it in dependencies. (if min SDK < 21)